# getting 400 error on login using expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

hi i am learning expressjs, and i am facing an error in below code. I should get incorrect username if i enter wrong username., but i am getting 400 error everytime i enter wrong email or password

**Login.js**

```
    try {
        const user = await loginSchema.findOne({email : req.body.email});

        if (!user) {
            throw new Error({ error: 'Incorrect username' })
        }
        const isPasswordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password)

        if (!isPasswordMatch) {
            throw new Error({ error: 'Incorrect password' })
        }
       
        res.send({user})
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).send(error)
    }
});
```

Comment: So what comes back as `user` and `isPasswordMatch`? The problem is that you don't get `null` or `undefined` from the server, therefore `(!user)` does not return false (perhaps it returns some json error?). Then, when you try to send the user, you get the 400 error.

Comment: Well you're throwing an error inside your try block. This error will be caught by the catch block. Hence the 400 error. Also new error can just receive a string and doesn't need an object

Comment: @feedy i am getting Null, even when document is present in collection. i am using mongodb.

Comment: @theblackgigant is right. Do not throw an error in your 'try' statement. Either display a popup, print it in the console etc. The error you throw is caught and then send as 400.

Comment: @feedy i cannot display popup. its a restapi.

Comment: Well don't set the status then. Just do `res.send(error)` Or do:
`if (error == 'Incorrect username' || error == 'Incorrect password') {
   res.send(error);
 }
 else {
   res.status(400).send(error); //or whatever
 }`

In the case with the Or statements, you might need to do 'error.error', I am not sure, but you can easily figure it out

Comment: Sorry can't edit my last comment for some reason - you may also want to use status 401 rather than 400